# AWS EC2 (batch) throttling connection?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-batch

So I am running a script on aws batch that fetches 100,000+ domains.

- The script runs in a docker container.
- The domains are randomized and in a redis queue.
- The script pulls 20,000 domains from the queue, processes them and then writes results to redis again.

When I run the script on an EC2 instance that I launched I get.

```
AMI: Custom
EBS Optimized: True

Time Elapsed : 2007.7330884933472
Good Domains : 53517
Processed Domains: 240000
```

When I run it on an EC2 instance spun up by batch I get:

```
AMI: Amazon Linux AMI 2017.03.e x86_64 ECS HVM
EBS Optimized: False

Time Elapsed : 2313.34757232666
New Domains : 51243
Processed Domains: 400000
```

Are the instance's that AWS batch spins up throttling my connection? Because I am using Docker I just can't think of why the results would be different other than bandwidth issues. The Docker image is stored in ECS and pulled down and then the script run.

I have run this test over millions of randomized domains and the results are the same so statistically speaking its not to do with the sampling of domains either. Also the good domain rate is 2x on an instance I spin up that vs batch.

**UPDATE 1**: Differences, EBS is True on one and False on the other. But I can't seem to change that with AWS batch.

**UPDATE 2**: Tested EBS False for a machine with lower specs and still can't account for lower network performance. Maybe its the AMI?

**UPDATE 3**: I tested the AMI and that could be the problem ami-c6f81abe used on batch. Not sure why yet.

**UPDATE 4**: Turns out it was ulimit parameter on the jobDefinition that was causing my problem.

Comment: What instance types are you using? Is there any difference there in perf at network or location in regards to your redis queue.

Comment: JamesKn redis: cache.m3.large, both EC2 on batch and off batch are m4.large

Comment: Glen Thompson: Are they in the same availability zones inside the same region? (I am guessing yes) Noticed there is not Time Elapsed in the question on Ec2?

Comment: JamesKn: Sorry I just updated the question they are both in same region 'us-west-2'. I think it has to do with something around the boot process of the instance or that its a different AMI? something like this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/virtualization_types.html or this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/enhanced-networking.html

Comment: Just checked and they are both HVM virtualization type.

Comment: I added the AIM's

Comment: Hmm EBS-optimized: False for the batch EC2 and True for the once I launched... Do you think that could be it?

Comment: Glen Thompson : that might be the difference as that will certain change perf for networking at least. Can you true and re-run the test.  What disks did you have for both then?

Comment: Looks like http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/batch.html#Batch.Client.create_compute_environment you can't set that? Should be default on m4.large http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSOptimized.html